# change the words "Wordpress running on theme" in "At a glance",especially the link "theme.php"

Tags: dashboard

l just wanna change words "wordpress x.x.x running on theme"in "At a glance",actually l wanna remove the link "theme.php".l added the code in my function.php:

```
    add_filter('gettext', 'remove_admin_stuff', 20, 3);

function remove_admin_stuff( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain ) {

    $custom_field_text = 'You are using <span class="b">WordPress %s</span>.';

    if ( is_admin() && $untranslated_text === $custom_field_text ) {
        return '';
    }

    return $translated_text;
}
```

wanna make a trick.but it failed .please help me.

Comment: Your function returns empty string or `$translated_text` which was not modified.

Answer (score 0):

> This code may help you.

```
function wpfi_change_text( $translated_text ) {
        if ( $translated_text == 'ORIGINAL TEXT' ) {
            $translated_text = '';
        }
        return $translated_text;
    }
    add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpfi_change_text', 20 );
```